# Nested Grouping with Crossfilter?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

New to cross filter and working on a project that needs to maintain summed totals and peak values of those summed totals over a date range.

Tried to utilize the [complex reduction](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/complex-reduce.html) from the dc.js examples.

I was able to get the max of a specific make and model over the date range but not the summed total peak (summed by day) for say the Region dimension or color dimension.

The project requires the following charts.

- A bar chart that shows the total daily peak inventory count by region(s)
- A selectable menu that has the make & model and their respective daily peak for the data set
- A selectable menu that has the color and its respective daily peak for the data set

Below is a sample of the data *(With the exclusion of the date being converted to a date object.)*

```
var carData = [
    {Date: "11/26/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'SW', 'Make and Model': 'buick enclave' , 'Inventory Count': 12710, Color: 'charcoal' ,'Color Inventory': 3665},
    {Date: "11/26/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'SW', 'Make and Model': 'chevrolet 1500' , 'Inventory Count': 8510, Color: 'brown', 'Color Inventory': 2520},
    {Date: "11/26/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NE', 'Make and Model': 'chevrolet camaro', 'Inventory Count': 5250, Color: 'silver', 'Color Inventory': 750},
    {Date: "11/26/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NW', 'Make and Model': 'chevrolet malibu', 'Inventory Count': 4300, Color: 'brown','Color Inventory': 2100},
    {Date: "11/26/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NW', 'Make and Model': 'dodge coupe', 'Inventory Count': 15100, Color: 'silver', 'Color Inventory': 5200},
    {Date: "11/26/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NE', 'Make and Model': 'jeep compass', 'Inventory Count': 7300, Color: 'blue', 'Color Inventory': 2300},
    {Date: "11/26/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NE', 'Make and Model': 'kia forte', 'Inventory Count': 4250,Color: 'white', 'Color Inventory': 2200},
    {Date: "11/26/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'SW', 'Make and Model': 'kia sorento', 'Inventory Count': 9450,Color: 'red', 'Color Inventory': 6525},
    {Date: "11/27/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'SW', 'Make and Model': 'buick enclave' , 'Inventory Count': 11251, Color: 'charcoal' ,'Color Inventory': 2206},
    {Date: "11/27/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'SW', 'Make and Model': 'chevrolet 1500' , 'Inventory Count': 8246, Color: 'brown', 'Color Inventory': 2256},
    {Date: "11/27/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NE', 'Make and Model': 'chevrolet camaro', 'Inventory Count': 5200, Color: 'silver', 'Color Inventory': 700},
    {Date: "11/27/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NW', 'Make and Model': 'chevrolet malibu', 'Inventory Count': 4250, Color: 'brown','Color Inventory': 2050},
    {Date: "11/27/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NW', 'Make and Model': 'dodge coupe', 'Inventory Count': 15000, Color: 'silver', 'Color Inventory': 5100},
    {Date: "11/27/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NE', 'Make and Model': 'jeep compass', 'Inventory Count': 7200, Color: 'blue', 'Color Inventory': 2200},
    {Date: "11/27/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NE', 'Make and Model': 'kia forte', 'Inventory Count': 4150,Color: 'white', 'Color Inventory': 2100},
    {Date: "11/27/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'SW', 'Make and Model': 'kia sorento', 'Inventory Count': 8953,Color: 'red', 'Color Inventory': 6058}
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put your question another way, you want to group by both color and day, and then find the max day for each color.

I'm going to assume you are also using dc.js since you mention it in your question. What we'll do is keep a running count of days for each color. Then, in the [value accessor](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BaseMixin.html#valueAccessor__anchor), we will find the max.

This is more efficient than calculating the maximum during group reduction.

```
const cf = crossfilter(carData),
  colorDimension = cf.dimension(({Color}) => Color),
  colorDayGroup = colorDimension.group().reduce(
    (p, v) => { // add
      const day = d3.timeDay(v.Date).getTime(); // 2. round to day, convert to int
      p[day] = (p[day] || 0) + v['Color Inventory']; // 3
      return p;
    },
    (p, v) => { // remove
      const day = d3.timeDay(v.Date).getTime(); // round to day, convert to int
      p[day] = (p[day] || 0) - v['Color Inventory']; // 4
      return p;
    },
    () => ({}) // 1. init
  );
```

1. Each bin is a map from integer days to color sums
2. We use [d3.timeDay](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/v2.0.0/README.md#timeDay) to round date objects to days - not needed in this example, but this would matter if the dates have times.
3. When adding a row to a bin, lookup the day. If it does not exist, default it to zero. Then add the color inventory field.
4. Same thing for removing a row, but we subtract.

Use it with a `valueAccessor` like this:

```
chart.valueAccessor(({key, value}) => d3.max(Object.values(value)))
```

This retrieves all the counts from the day->count object and finds the max count.

I used [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/dzp5a9hn/14/) to test. I changed the value of

```
{Date: "11/27/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NE', 'Make and Model': 'kia forte', 'Inventory Count': 4150,Color: 'white', 'Color Inventory': 2700},
```

because 11/26 was the max day for every color, and I wanted to exercise the code better.

To test, I mapped each value using the value accessor:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(colorDayGroup.all().map(({key, value}) => ({key, value: d3.max(Object.values(value))})), null, 2))
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "key": "blue",
    "value": 2300
  },
  {
    "key": "brown",
    "value": 4620
  },
  {
    "key": "charcoal",
    "value": 3665
  },
  {
    "key": "red",
    "value": 6525
  },
  {
    "key": "silver",
    "value": 5950
  },
  {
    "key": "white",
    "value": 2700
  }
]
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help and quick response.

Comment: I am using DC.js and curious how you might use define composite bar chart that displayed the Peak Inventory and Peak Color Inventory on the X axis. The part that confuses me is setting of the Peak Inventory dim so that the X axis is labeled Peak Inventory.

Comment: The x axis label is [just a property](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/CoordinateGridMixin.html#xAxisLabel). Not sure I understand your question. I’m also not sure what kind of composite bar chart you’re talking about - usually bars are stacked, or a bar chart is composited with a line chart?

Comment: Yeah a little confusing but I was thinking of something like [composite example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/composite.html) but instead of two line charts it would consist of two bar charts. To simplify my follow up question; Using your example I created a group by Make and Model as the key and Inventory count as the value. If I wanted to create a simple bar chart with no filters applied, it would have one chart column of total showing the aggregated Peak Inventory sum instead of each make and model. I hope this makes a little more sense and thanks again for your help!

Comment: But it would be confusing to draw bar charts on top of each other, right? That's why bars are usually stacked. There have been proposals for [grouped bars](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/1470), is that what you mean? Unfortunately we haven't found a good way to merge this feature, but my colleague is working in that direction.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. In short I am looking for a single data point that sums the peak values into a total value. For the example above a single bar of 25,760 would be displayed for the sum of the peak Color Inventory.

Comment: I see, it's not really a composite chart, but a sum total. Still, it sounds like a different question and it would require a little bit of code to answer it. Would you display it a simple number display or something? Anyway, please open another question since it's not good to go into in-depth Q&A in the comments section.

Comment: [Follow up Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65192607/conditional-custom-x-value-dim-name-when-no-filters-are-applied-to-dc-js-chart) Hey Gordon thanks again for you help.  I opened a new question if you have some time to review it.

Comment: For the valueAccessor above how might I return a percentile for a [SelectMenu](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/SelectMenu.html)  I've used  `d3.format(".0%")` on y axis for other charts but not sure how I might apply that to the values being displayed in a Select Menu

Comment: It’s somewhat non standard but the SelectMenu uses the [title accessor](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BaseMixin.html#title) to format the text for the options. Normally I think “label” would be more appropriate; I guess the author wanted the default “key: value” text that is usually in tooltips.