# Conditional custom X Value dim name when no filters are applied to DC.js Chart

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Had a follow-up question [Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65160017/nested-grouping-with-crossfilter) which was to group by both color and day, and then find the max day for each color. Gordon did a great job explaining how to keep a running sum for each color per day and find the max. Now I am trying to show the total sum of all colors and their respective peaks in a bar chart.

In short I am looking for a single data point that sums the peak values into a total value and displays Total. I am confused what I should use for the dimension as I want a custom X dim value named TOTAL instead of a list of all of the colors. For the original example a single bar with a value of 25,760 would be displayed for the sum of the peak Color Inventory.

```
var carData = [
    {Date: "11/26/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'SW', 'Make and Model': 'buick enclave' , 'Inventory Count': 12710, Color: 'charcoal' ,'Color Inventory': 3665},
    {Date: "11/26/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'SW', 'Make and Model': 'chevrolet 1500' , 'Inventory Count': 8510, Color: 'brown', 'Color Inventory': 2520},
    {Date: "11/26/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NE', 'Make and Model': 'chevrolet camaro', 'Inventory Count': 5250, Color: 'silver', 'Color Inventory': 750},
    {Date: "11/26/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NW', 'Make and Model': 'chevrolet malibu', 'Inventory Count': 4300, Color: 'brown','Color Inventory': 2100},
    {Date: "11/26/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NW', 'Make and Model': 'dodge coupe', 'Inventory Count': 15100, Color: 'silver', 'Color Inventory': 5200},
    {Date: "11/26/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NE', 'Make and Model': 'jeep compass', 'Inventory Count': 7300, Color: 'blue', 'Color Inventory': 2300},
    {Date: "11/26/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NE', 'Make and Model': 'kia forte', 'Inventory Count': 4250,Color: 'white', 'Color Inventory': 2200},
    {Date: "11/26/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'SW', 'Make and Model': 'kia sorento', 'Inventory Count': 9450,Color: 'red', 'Color Inventory': 6525},
    {Date: "11/27/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'SW', 'Make and Model': 'buick enclave' , 'Inventory Count': 11251, Color: 'charcoal' ,'Color Inventory': 2206},
    {Date: "11/27/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'SW', 'Make and Model': 'chevrolet 1500' , 'Inventory Count': 8246, Color: 'brown', 'Color Inventory': 2256},
    {Date: "11/27/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NE', 'Make and Model': 'chevrolet camaro', 'Inventory Count': 5200, Color: 'silver', 'Color Inventory': 700},
    {Date: "11/27/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NW', 'Make and Model': 'chevrolet malibu', 'Inventory Count': 4250, Color: 'brown','Color Inventory': 2050},
    {Date: "11/27/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NW', 'Make and Model': 'dodge coupe', 'Inventory Count': 15000, Color: 'silver', 'Color Inventory': 5100},
    {Date: "11/27/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NE', 'Make and Model': 'jeep compass', 'Inventory Count': 7200, Color: 'blue', 'Color Inventory': 2200},
    {Date: "11/27/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'NE', 'Make and Model': 'kia forte', 'Inventory Count': 4150,Color: 'white', 'Color Inventory': 2100},
    {Date: "11/27/2020", 'Inventory Region': 'SW', 'Make and Model': 'kia sorento', 'Inventory Count': 8953,Color: 'red', 'Color Inventory': 6058}
];
```

Here is the group reduce function from the previous answer:

```
const cf = crossfilter(carData),
  colorDimension = cf.dimension(({Color}) => Color),
  colorDayGroup = colorDimension.group().reduce(
    (p, v) => { // add
      const day = d3.timeDay(v.Date).getTime(); // 2. round to day, convert to int
      p[day] = (p[day] || 0) + v['Color Inventory']; // 3
      return p;
    },
    (p, v) => { // remove
      const day = d3.timeDay(v.Date).getTime(); // round to day, convert to int
      p[day] = (p[day] || 0) - v['Color Inventory']; // 4
      return p;
    },
    () => ({}) // 1. init
  );
```

and the value accessor which calculates the max:

```
chart.valueAccessor(({key, value}) => d3.max(Object.values(value)))
```

Comment: You’re looking for a single value to display as a number, like with the dc.js numberDisplay widget? If so it will probably take a fake groupAll object, that is, an object with a method `.value()` that returns the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a single value to supply to the dc.js [NumberDisplay widget](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/NumberDisplay.html), the best way to get it in there is to supply a [fake groupAll](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groupall) object, that is, an object with the single method `.value()`, which returns the value.

Here, we want it to take the sum of the max value from each bin:

```
function sum_peaks_groupAll(group) {
  return {
    value: () => d3.sum(group.all(), ({value}) => d3.max(Object.values(value)))
  };
}
const sumPeaks = sum_peaks_groupAll(colorDayGroup);
```

For historic reasons, the number display widget requires passing the identity function as value accessor when using a groupAll object for its group:

```
number.group(sumPeaks)
  .valueAccessor(d => d);
```

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/dzp5a9hn/33/).

#### Bar chart with single bar

If you want a bar chart displaying this sum, then you want an ordinary [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups). It's the same calculation but a method named `.all()` that returns an array with a single element which is a key/value pair:

```
function sum_peaks_group(group) {
  return {
    all: () => ([{
      key: 'All',
      value: d3.sum(group.all(), ({value}) => d3.max(Object.values(value)))
    }])
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why the group shows undefined when trying to build a composite? [Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/kxr29a1c/)

Comment: I am not sure why, but you need to supply a dimension and group to the composite chart as well as its children. Also, a composite chart just overlays the two charts, so it doesn't make much sense for bar charts. Here is an example which [combines the two fake groups](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/h78dcu64/12/) and creates a bar chart showing both Peak bars.